# Getting PHP variable into Chart Script

Tags: php, html, charts

I am having an issue with Google Charts. I have created the exact format it shows in the example inside a PHP vaiable

```
['Time','Devices'],['08-12-2015 09:19:00',12],['08-12-2015 09:20:00',26],['08-12-2015 09:21:00',23],['08-12-2015 09:22:00',16],['08-12-2015 09:23:00',29],['08-12-2015 09:24:00',21],['08-12-2015 09:25:00',18],['08-12-2015 09:26:00',28],['08-12-2015 09:27:00',19],['08-12-2015 09:28:00',15],['08-12-2015 09:29:00',25],['08-12-2015 09:30:00',18],['08-12-2015 09:31:00',18],['08-12-2015 09:32:00',26],['08-12-2015 09:33:00',13],['08-12-2015 09:34:00',16],['08-12-2015 09:35:00',19],['08-12-2015 09:36:00',14],['08-12-2015 09:37:00',23],['08-12-2015 09:38:00',16],['08-12-2015 09:39:00',12],['08-12-2015 09:40:00',27],['08-12-2015 09:41:00',17],['08-12-2015 09:42:00',16],['08-12-2015 09:43:00',32],['08-12-2015 09:44:00',20],['08-12-2015 09:45:00',18],['08-12-2015 09:46:00',30],['08-12-2015 09:47:00',14],['08-12-2015 09:48:00',19],['08-12-2015 09:49:00',24],['08-12-2015 09:50:00',12],['08-12-2015 09:51:00',23],['08-12-2015 09:52:00',21],['08-12-2015 09:53:00',12],['08-12-2015 09:54:00',26],['08-12-2015 09:55:00',23],['08-12-2015 09:56:00',12],['08-12-2015 09:57:00',32],['08-12-2015 09:58:00',16],['08-12-2015 09:59:00',18],['08-12-2015 10:00:00',23],['08-12-2015 10:01:00',17],['08-12-2015 10:02:00',19],['08-12-2015 10:03:00',39],['08-12-2015 10:04:00',16],['08-12-2015 10:05:00',17],['08-12-2015 10:06:00',27],['08-12-2015 10:07:00',21],['08-12-2015 10:08:00',18],['08-12-2015 10:09:00',40],['08-12-2015 10:10:00',20],['08-12-2015 10:11:00',18],['08-12-2015 10:12:00',28],['08-12-2015 10:13:00',25],['08-12-2015 10:14:00',17],['08-12-2015 10:15:00',32],['08-12-2015 10:16:00',25],['08-12-2015 10:17:00',16],['08-12-2015 10:18:00',31]
```

I now want to place this inside the Chart example below but it does not work.

The variable that holds the above information is $outp. I tried to place it in  but it does not work.

```
<html>
 <head>
     <script type="text/javascript"
                 src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
                     'modules':[{
                         'name':'visualization',
                         'version':'1',
                         'packages':['corechart']
                     }]
                 }"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

         function drawChart() {
             var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          <?php echo $optp; ?>
        ]);

             var options = {
                 title: 'Company Performance',
                 curveType: 'function',
                 legend: { position: 'bottom' }
             };

             var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

             chart.draw(data, options);
         }
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If anyone can assist please, its driving me crazy.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: And all of a sudden this actually worked? Very Strange. Must have Ghost's in my machine.